# Can I force import dependency as pure?

Tags: javascript, webpack, tree-shaking

For example, I'm using `mustache` in my library, but it used only in exportable function

```js
import mustache from 'mustache'

export function some() {
  ...
  mustache
  ...
}

export function other() {
  ...
}
```

When I importing only `other` from this library and build bundle using webpack, webpack include `mustache`'s code because it think what code of `mustache` is not pure.

Can I somehow mark `mustache` import as pure?

Answer (score 0):

I think Webpack will always bundle `mustache` when you import it.

Maybe you can split your library into several files:

`some.js`

```
import mustache from 'mustache'

export default function some() {
  ...
  mustache
  ...
}
```

and `other.js`

```
export default function other() {
  ...
}
```

and create main `index.js` file which is the default export and combines the above:

```
import some from './some';
import other from './other';

export default {
  some,
  other,
};
```

This way your library can be consumed as the whole (via `index.js`) or in parts - `some.js` or `other.js` (which will not include `mustache` with it).

```
// you can use the whole library as
import library from 'library';

// or you can use any part, for example 'other' (without mustache)
import other from 'library/other';
```